# How to find distance between two points on a line in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, gis, oracle-spatial

I have a point on line and the start vertex of that line.*SDO_GEOM.SDO_DISTANCE* finds the aerial distance between the points, but is there any function in oracle that finds the distance on line instead of the aerial distance? or is there any function in Oracle similar to **ST_LineSubstring** in Postgis?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with some sample code that demonstrates the issue you are having. I.e. add DDL/DML statements for your tables & sample data and your current query and the errors/issues with this query.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the doc for the SDO_LRS package, [SDO_LRS.GEOM_SEGMENT_LENGTH](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/spatl/SDO_LRS-reference.html#GUID-F21FD7B2-2B02-489F-A00B-87CDB809FC82). It explains this function, as well as how to get something using the measure functions of SDO_LRS. (The doc is from 19c)

Answer (score -1):

You may use SDO_GEOM.SDO_LENGTH

Comment: It calculates the shortest distance not the distance along the line.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please add an explanation to your answer why you this its solves the problem. Just giving a value won't help people trying to understand the issue.

Comment: Hi, May be this link helps you: https://spatialdbadvisor.com/oracle_spatial_tips_tricks/297/how-to-calculate-cumulative-length-of-a-linestring